# Axios retry request forgets headers

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an axios request interceptor that adds bearer authorization via an access token. I also have a response interceptor that catches 'token expired' responses, gets a new token via a refresh mechanism, and retries the original request. This seems like it should work, except when the original request is retried, it seems to have lost all its headers. This confuses my API backend as it expects a `Content-Type` (which was there in the original request).

Note: I'm familiar with the large number of questions about why axios doesn't respect a custom `Content-Type` header. That's not my problem -- I'm not setting one -- axios does a fine job determining that on its own. I'm just confused at why the `Content-Type` header that axios sets itself is getting removed when resending the original request.

Relevant code:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://www.mycoolapi.com",
  timeout: 5000,
  withCredentials: true,
});

api.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
    // Add the auth header (not messing with any other headers)
    config.headers!.Authorization = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    return config;
  }, (error) => Promise.reject(error));

api.interceptors.response.use((response) => response,
  async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status == 401 && refreshToken && !error.config._isRetry) {
      // Token expired? Refresh, then retry the original request
      error.config._isRetry = true;
      await refreshLogIn();
      return api(error.config);
    }
  
    throw error;
  });

async function refreshLogIn() {
  // Use the refresh token to get a new token pair
  const response = await api.post( "/token",
    new URLSearchParams({
      grant_type: "refresh_token",
      refresh_token: refreshToken,
    })
  );

  accessToken = response.data["access_token"];
  refreshToken = response.data["refresh_token"];
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on `return api(error.config)` in the response interceptor, and inspect the original request (which is in `error.config`), I get the following headers (reminder, I added only the `Authorization` header, the rest are axios defaults or calculated from the requeset):

[image]

If I then step through to the request interceptor where the original response is being retried, I get these headers instead:

[image]

`Content-Type` has been removed, along with what was in `Symbol(defaults)` (whatever that is).

What am I missing here?

Comment: What version of Axios are you using?

Comment: I would advise **not** using Axios v1.x at all. Here's the relevant issue https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5089

Comment: 1.0.0. That's it.  I did run across that issue in my Googling but didn't read past the title. The last version before 1.0.0 is 0.27.2... try that one? Or is it going to break a bunch of other things?

Comment: IMO v0.27.2 is the last stable version of Axios. v1.0.0 and beyond are utterly broken in numerous ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Phil noted in the comments, this is a bug in `axios` >= 1.0.0. I suppose one could downgrade to 0.27.2, but I just rewrote using good old `fetch`. My use case was simple enough anyway, and one less dependency is never a bad thing.